# Como criar novas pasta em um projeto do Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Sou iniciante no Android Studio e estou tentando criar novas pastas (values-ldpi, values-mdip e etc..) na estrutura do projeto, mas não encontro opção.

Comment: Qual é exatamente a dificuldade? Tudo que você precisa fazer é abrir o menu de contexto em cima da pasta `res` e então `New > Folder`.

Comment: Consegui agora o meu problema é que a pespectiva que mostrava o projeto estava exibindo apenas o pacote, mudei o escopo para project files e agora consigo visualizar todas as pastas (antes não visualizava a pasta res).

Comment: A solução no meu caso foi ir em res -> New -> Android Resource Directory

Comment: Opa, desculpe. Confundi o Android Studio com o ADT, que eu costumo usar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a opção pra criar pasta é **Directory** veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado @aldison o problema foi resolvido.