# Ao criar pasta dentro da pasta /res ela não fica visível no painel da esquerda

Tags: android, android-studio

Quando coloco o nome da nova pasta e pressiono Enter, essa mesma pasta não aparece no lado esquerdo do Projecto nem consigo referenciar o caminho dela.

O estranho é que se eu colocar o nome da pasta como raw, anim, animator, menu, color, xml essa aparece, já outros nome não.
Tão pouco consigo criar hierarquia entre as pastas.

[image: Criar uma nova Pasta ou Diretório no Android Studio]

Comment: Pela imagem você quer criar um directório debaixo da pasta **/res**, nesse caso deve usar a opção **"Android resource directory"**

Comment: Quando uso a opção Android resource directory também não cria uma pasta visível no lado esquerdo da aplicação. A menos que mudo o modo de visualização no entanto enquanto estiver programando também não consigo referenciar a pasta...

Comment: Acho que pode ajuda-lo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454427/new-directory-vs-new-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como criar novas pasta em um projeto do Android Studio](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6309/como-criar-novas-pasta-em-um-projeto-do-android-studio)

Comment: Antes de responder, pergunto, para que queres criar uma pasta nos resources?

Comment: @seamusd não é duplicata, se estivesse atento veria que ele tem no post dele a resposta da outra pergunta. O problema aqui é outro.

Comment: @JorgeB. Antes de perceber que o Android já tinha estruturas bem definidas de pastas padrão para tudo quanto preciso, eu tentei criar pastas específicas para animação, para som e para algumas fotos para diferentes partes do projeto, foi por este motivo que eu queria criar uma nova pasta mas com nomes diferentes do padrão...

Comment: Você pode criar essas pastas, o problema é que elas não são reconhecidas como tendo *resources*, não poderá referenciá-las, tanto no código como no xml, porque não é gerada uma entrada na classe *R*

Comment: Muito grato @ramaral, como conclusão então sou obrigado mesmo a usar as pastas pré-definidas, para poder referências mais tarde no XML bem como no código Java, certo?

Comment: Os nomes *layout*, *drawable*, etc, sim. Mas elas podem ser criadas em várias pastas de *resources*. Além de `src/main/res` pode criar outras por ex: `src/main/res2`. Use, no arquivo *build.gradle*, a propriedade `res.srcDirs` no bloco `sourceSets` para as indicar como pastas de *resources*.

Answer (score 5):

As pastas de uma aplicação Android seguem uma estrutura e nomes de pastas bem definida.

A vista ["Android"](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html#ProjectFiles) não reflecte totalmente a hierarquia das pastas existentes no projecto, apenas são visualizadas as pastas "tipo" que compõem essa estrutura, por exemplo não são listadas as pastas com qualificadores.

Repare que apenas aparece uma pasta **/res/mimpap**, apesar de existirem as pastas **/res/mipmap-hdpi, /res/mipmap-mdpi**, etc.

Note que os nomes de pastas que referiu, *raw, anim, animator, menu, color e xml*, são listados porque fazem parte da [lista](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) de nomes definidos para *resources*.

Apesar de poder criar outras pastas, elas não são reconhecidas como tendo *resources*, não conseguirá referenciar os arquivos nelas, tanto no código como no xml, porque não é gerada uma entrada na classe **R**.

É no entanto possível ter essas pastas(as da [lista](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)) dentro de outra que não apenas a `src/main/res`, pode criar outras como por ex: `src/main/res2`. Use, no arquivo *build.gradle*, a propriedade `res.srcDirs` no bloco `sourceSets` para as indicar como pasta de *resources*.

```
android{

    ....
    ....
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs += ['src/main/res2']
        }
    }
}
```

Para visualizar todas as pasta escolha as vistas "Project" ou "Packages".

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Para criar uma sub-pasta em **/res** deve clicar com o botão direito, sobre ele, e escolher **new**->**Android resource directory**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No *wizard* aberto deve escolher o *resource* pretendido e o qualificador a aplicar, **não mexa no Directory Name**.

O exemplo seguinte mostra como criar uma pasta de *resource* do tipo *layout* e com o qualificador *Portaint*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Normalmente não é necessário criar essas pastas, ao criar um arquivo do tipo "Android resource file", se a pasta não existir ela será criada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No *wizard* que abre introduza o nome do *resource*, escolha o seu tipo e o qualificador, além do arquivo também será criada(caso não exista) a respectiva pasta com o qualificador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Sugiro que vc altere o modo de visualização de seu projeto. Teste utilizando o modo Project Files... neste modo você tem acesso a estrutura de arquivos, pelo gerenciador de arquivos do Studio.

t+

[image: captura de tela studio...]

Answer (score 3):

A pasta RES não permite criar sub-pastas. Você pode usar um plugin para simular pastas na RES baseado nos nomes dos arquivos.

Nome: Android File Grouping

Para adicionar à IDE, aperta ctrl+alt+s e vá em Plugins e pesquise por Android File Grouping.
Para usar, clique na pasta layout com o direito e vá em Group (tem que ir no modo de visualização "Project")

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite galerinha tudo bem? Respondendo a primeira pergunta a pasta criada não aparece mesmo, tenta desta forma funcionou para mim. CLICA A SETA DA PASTA RES/ EM SEGUIDA NA BARRA QUE MOSTRA CADA DIRETÓRIO ABERTO CLIQUE EM RES/ NOVAMENTE QUE SUA PASTA CRIADA ESTARÁ LÁ AI É SÓ SELECIONA-LÁ, ESPERO TER AJUDADO.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]