# Criando uma subpasta no drawable Android Studio

Tags: android, drawable

Eu quero criar uma subpasta no drawable porque estou usando muitas imagens em minha aplicação e gostaria de organizá-las. Como faço para criar e deixar a pasta visível para ser utilizada?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o Android Studio com o Gradle para ter múltiplos diretórios de recursos, em app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    ....
    android.sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs = ['src/main/pastaextra_carros', 'src/main/res']
    }
    ....
}
```

Entretanto os nomes dos arquivos destas pastas não podem ser os mesmos, o que significa que você ainda terá de utilizar a nomenclatura de carros_vermelho.png e computadores_vermelho.png

Comment: Fiz o que você disse, mas as pastas não ficam visíveis e nem consigo ter acesso a elas.

Comment: @MariaLins veja [Por que depois de criar uma pasta ela não fica visível no painel da esquerda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150385/2541)