# Visualização do projeto no android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Por que a visualização dos itens do meu projeto no android studio mudou?
Só desse projeto tá assim, dos outros estão normal.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionado [Por que depois de criar uma pasta ela não fica visível no painel da esquerda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150385/2541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está em modo de visualização `Project`. Clique na seta acima da listagem de arquivos e selecione `Android` para voltar pra visualização resumida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: era exatamente isso